# Mapbox-gl: flyTo feature with certain property

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have been playing around with mapbox-gl.  I am trying to get the map to `flyTo()` a specific polygon in one of my layers.

After looking extensively through the API I can only find methods to return features after clicking the map or selecting with a bounding box -- no method to parse the features of a layer and its attributes.

I want the latlon (or bounding box or whatever) of a polygon in the dataset, where "NBHD_NAME" equals the variable I am searching for.  I am using a polygon PBF hosted on Mapbox.  I cannot seem to access the features of the vector layer through `map.getLayer()` or `map.getSource()`.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this functionality not really present in mapbox-gl?

Answer (score 1):

To get features within a vector tile dataset you can use the method querySourceFeatures:

```
map.on('style.load', function() {
    var features = map.querySourceFeatures('SOURCE_NAME', {
        sourceLayer: 'SOURCE_LAYER_NAME',
        filter: ["==", "NBHD_NAME", "YOUR_VARIABLE"]
    });
});
```

This will return an geoJson.

See the documentation here:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#querySourceFeatures